# Sqlite insert very slow

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I am trying to understand why Sqlite inserts are so very slow in our system. So I wrote a small test project. All it does is write 1 row into a table. That tiny insert takes 150ms!

I am aware that a transaction opens underneath. That still makes it much too long.

I've tried adding PRAGMA synchronous=OFF and PRAGMA locking_mode=exclusive. No change.

Here is the test code:

```
class Program
{
    static SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        initDB();

        writeToDb();

        m_dbConnection.Close();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void writeToDb()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        string sql = "insert into highscores (name, score) values ('Me', 9001)";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);

        sw.Restart();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Console.WriteLine("Writing to db took {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    private static void initDB()
    {
        SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.sqlite");

        m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
        m_dbConnection.Open();

        string sql = "CREATE TABLE highscores (name VARCHAR(20), score INT)";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to write 10, 100, 1.000, 10.000 ... rows in a row?

Comment: Agree with @Fildor, why do you think it's too slow to insert 1 record? You aren't going to multiply received value by `N` I hope. [Tests](https://www.sqlite.org/speed.html) are staring from 1000 and at 25000 it's already very impressive (ignore red text, red text is meant to confuse people). Keyword is **transaction** (if you plan to do proper testing).

Comment: This question will be better suited for CodeReview.